# Hiding plus and dropdown icon Ubuntu 16.04 terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, icons, appearance

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and liked it so far. The only thing that is bugging me is the plus and dropdown icon that appear in the terminal when you open multiple tabs, see screenshot below. Is there any way to hide this? Or revert back to the old version of the terminal. What are the advantages of the new version?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Terminal with to tabs]

Edit: I found out that it is possible to edit CSS style of GTK3.0 Gnome Terminal by creating `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. However, does anyone know what the classes for the two icons on the right are? That way I can simply add `display: none`.

Edit 2: Apparently it is not possible to give an "display" attribute to GTK CSS. Is there any other way to hide elements in GTK CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way, although there might be. I'm far more comfortable to suggest that you should check out some [other terminal applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341272/is-there-an-alternative-to-gnome-terminal). Terminator is my favourite, it allows you to "split" a terminal with minimal borders and gives you 2 terminals in 1 window, makes everything look real nice. All have their advantages and disadvantages so do take the time to find one that suits your needs and pleases your eye.

Comment: I understand. But as you might have noticed, hence the reason why I created this question, is that I find appearance just as important as functionality. Is it possible to theme Terminator? Or do you know any other terminal applications that are able to be themed?

Comment: You can theme the vast majority of terminal applications, Terminator only allows you (as I recall) to edit the colour scheme, which is usually sufficient. The alternatives listed there also have detailed breakdowns of what features they have. Tilda has a very highly configurable interface which you might appreciate. Wterm is also pretty configurable in terms of UI.