# How to make an invisible terminal(without the top bar as well) and then pin it to the top without interacting with it

Tags: unity, gui, window

I am not even sure if this is possible but I want to have a terminal window, that has transparent background and is pinned to the top but it doesn't react to any key press or mouse event at all.

Rather, the window behind it reacts to the key or mouse event.

What I really want to do is to run CAVA on it and then work on something else so that whatever I do, I can see the music bars and also do my work.

Comment: You can use drop-down terminal such as Guake, Tilda - see https://askubuntu.com/a/341289/66509 .